# How to show "Saving" text in a button when updating a field in Firestore?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I was working on a project. And I need to achieve this functionality. I have a simple button center of screen. And it has a child of `Text` widget. When widget tree rebuilding it gets a document from Cloud Firestore. Meanwhile, `Text` widget says "loading". After it gets the document, it shows a basic number field of the document like as "Value: 0".

---

When I press the button, it will increment the field called `value` in Cloud Firestore. It is working properly.

---

But, I also want to show a `Text` widget that says `Saving...` when I actually updating the `value`.

---

To sum up, updating process should go like that:
Value: 11 -> Pressed button -> Saving... -> Loading... -> Value: 12

---

How can I achieve this?

---

What I did so far?

```js
Future<String> getData() async {
  var fb = Firestore.instance;

  DocumentSnapshot dr =
      (await fb.collection("records").document("the record").get());

  return dr.data["value"].toString();
}

void updateData(int value) async {
  var fb = Firestore.instance;

  await fb.collection("records").document("the record").updateData({
    "value": value + 1,
  });
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Homework 4"),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder(
              future: getData(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return RaisedButton(
                    child: Text("Loading"),
                    onPressed: null,
                  );
                }

                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                  return RaisedButton(
                    child: Text("Value: " + snapshot.data),
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        updateData(int.parse(snapshot.data));
                      });
                    },
                  );
                }

                return RaisedButton(
                  child: Text("saving"),
                  onPressed: null,
                );
              })),
     
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, call `setState` and show “Loading...” before doing `updateDate()`

You can then use `....get().then((result){ })` (not `whenComplete()`; this is good practice as it ensures that only successful futures may proceed with the next step).

Inside the `.then()` you can set the state to show “Saving ...” and call the fetching function.

The fetch function itself can have another `.then()` to call `setState` again and show the “Value: 0”

While it might seem wise to use `FutureBuilder` I would say the requirement of having to show “Saving” during the update would make the solution equally as convoluted.

I was thinking that the solution involving a `FutureBuilder` would need some sort of flag variable to indicate that we are saving and inside the build function show a button with the `Text` “Saving” if the flag indicates that we are awaiting the update.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Dart. but you can use the `onCompleteListener` method from Firebase.
what you would do would be something like this:

1. when the user clicks save, change the text to saving
2. when the `onCompleteListener` is called you can change the text back

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I need a solution in dart.